# Python code to print elements from list that meet certain criteria

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list with 22 integers (ranging from 1 through 9) and want to create/ print a new list containing only those integers that are above 5.

This is what I have tried so far - the result (obviously) is that 'the_list' gets printed multiple times - i.e. the number of times = the number of instances above 5.

```
the_list = [1, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
print(the_list)

k=5
tl2=[]
for i in the_list:
    if i > k :
        tl2.append(the_list)
```

Comment: did you consider using list comprehension? `new_list = [i for i in the_list if i>5]`.

Comment: The only error in your code ` tl2.append(i)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
>>> the_list = [1, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> print(the_list)
[1, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> the_filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: x > 5, the_list))
>>> print(the_filtered_list)
[7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7]
```

See

- [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)
- [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)

**EDIT**:

Another option is to use a generator expression:

```
>>> the_filtered_list = list(i for i in the_list if i > 5)
>>> print(the_filtered_list)
[7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7]
```

See

- [generator expressions and list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions)

---

**EDIT:**

My initial answer was indeed slow and memory inefficient. Here is the comparison of several possibilities. Which one to choose depends on how big the list is and what it is used for later.

```
>>> import random
>>> import timeit
>>> import sys
>>> 
>>> the_list = [random.randrange(1, 10) for _ in range(100)]
>>> 
>>> timeit.timeit('filter(lambda x: x > 5, the_list)', setup=f'the_list = {the_list}')
0.15890196000000856
>>> timeit.timeit('[i for i in the_list if i > 5]', setup=f'the_list = {the_list}')
2.633208761999981
>>> timeit.timeit('(i for i in the_list if i > 5)', setup=f'the_list = {the_list}')
0.227755295999998
>>> 
>>> timeit.timeit('list(filter(lambda x: x > 5, the_list))', setup=f'the_list = {the_list}')
7.5565902380000125
>>> timeit.timeit('list(i for i in the_list if i > 5)', setup=f'the_list = {the_list}')
3.599053368
>>> 
>>> sys.getsizeof(filter(lambda x: x > 5, the_list))
64
>>> sys.getsizeof([i for i in the_list if i > 5])
440
>>> sys.getsizeof((i for i in the_list if i > 5))
128
>>> 
>>> sys.getsizeof(list(filter(lambda x: x > 5, the_list)))
480
>>> sys.getsizeof(list(i for i in the_list if i > 5))
480
```

Comment: `list(filter(lambda...` when a comprehension is that much shorter and more readable... just short of a downvote :)

Comment: filter with use of lambda is much slower compared to list comprehension.
`new_list = [i for i in the_list if i>5]` should be the ideal solution.

Comment: why `the_filtered_list = list(i for i in the_list if i > 5)` when you can do `the_filtered_list = [i for i in the_list if i > 5]` directly?

Comment: @PatrickArtner because it is faster and more memory-efficient. See my edit with speed and memory usage comparison

Comment: it should be noted that "memory efficient" depends on what you want to do further on - e.g. I don't see the point in `list(generator)` if you can have a `list` in the first place.

Comment: @Cloudomation `list(i for i in the_list if i > 5)` is slower than `[i for i in the_list if i > 5]`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are appending the list, not the number 'i'

```
the_list = [1, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
print(the_list)

k=5
tl2=[]
# the_list refers to the entire list
# i is an element in the list
for i in the_list:
   if i > k :
        # append  the number 'i'  if it is greater than k
        tl2.append(i)
print (t12)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
the_list = [1, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
print(the_list)
k=5
new_ls = [x for x in the_list if x >k]
print(new_ls)
```

try this solution